# interpreting deviance residual plot for response of negative binomial distribution

Tags: data-visualization, residuals, deviance

I have a big dataset on which I've used glm.nb(). I plotted the deviance residuals and got the plot below as the result. I do not understand what it means, why is it two "bands" of residuals?

[image]

Comment: Most likely you don't need to plot everything, maybe like plot(<response>[1:10000],<fit>$residuals[1:10000]) , it looks like you response variable basically goes into 2 values maybe 0 and 1.. again, this plot doesn't tell you much with the response

Comment: Have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html